# Less repetitive error handling jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling

I have a page with a lot of jquery requests.
I always add something like this to my calls...

```
error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
  {
        alert('Error in AJAX response.  Please see console log for details.');

    console.log(thrownError);
    console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
        console.log("responseText: "+ xhr.responseText);
        console.log("status: " + xhr.status);
  }
```

Question: Is there a simpler less repetitive way to do this? Rather than adding it to each request.

Comment: You can always extract that function to a named function and use that as the error value...

Comment: ....so simple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [`$.ajaxSetup()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/). You can do something like this once, and it will apply to all subsequent ajax calls you make via jQuery:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    error: function () {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Just be aware, *all* means exactly that. :)

Comment: I was looking for something like this, but I didn't think of the simple route above. Thank you both!